# Alternating colours per row per div using only css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to know if this is possible using only CSS:

```
Black White
White Black
Black White
White Black
```

The name represents the colour background I want. In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqxbvosx/), I've hardcoded it to show exactly what it is that I want, but the amount of divs will be dynamic, so I don't know how many there will be.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) here.

---

**OPTION 1**

This first option requires the use of 2 selectors

The first handles the styling of the divs in the left column of the grid. Numbering those ones gives us 1,5,9,13,... which you can express as `4n-3` (4*1-3=1, 4*2-3=5, 4*3-3=9, 4*4-3=13, ...). This can also be expressed as `4n+1`, if you prefer.

The second selector, to handle the styling of the divs in the right column, is more straightforward as that is simply every fourth `div`, which can be expressed as `4n` (4*1=4, 4*2=8, 4*3=12, 4*4=16, ...).

```css
div{
  background:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100px;
  width:50%;
}
div:nth-child(4n-3),div:nth-child(4n){
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

---

**OPTION 2**

This second option achieves the same result with a single selector using the [negation pseudo class `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

The inverse selection to that in option one can be expressed using `4n-1` and `4n-2` (or `4n+3` and `4n+2`) so we'll select all the divs, excluding those that match these expressions.

```css
div{
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:50%;
}
div:not(:nth-child(4n-1)):not(:nth-child(4n-2)){
    background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

---

**FURHTER READING ON [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)**

- [Overview of CSS pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)
- [More information on the `:nth-child` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- [More information on the negation pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

---

**ASIDE**

I tried my best to come up with a single CSS expression to suit this but couldn't. If anyone has any success doing so, please let me know. The sequence we're looking to match is: [`1,4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17,20,...,2n-(n%2)`](https://oeis.org/A042948)

Comment: I bow before thee, my king.

Comment: Side Note: You can accept an answer in 1 minute. :/

Comment: Good use of nth-child, good to see it done without [extra markup](http://jsfiddle.net/hqxbvosx/4/)

Comment: I've updated the answer above to include a second option that only uses a single selector.